# Recursive function can't read object property

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list

I made a function that turns an array into a list which is like this:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var result = null;
  for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: result
    }
  }
  return result
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]))
```

And then I tried to make a recursive function that takes a list and a number and returns an element at a given position in the list

Here's the first attempt:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var result = null;
  for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: result
    }
  }
  return result
}
function nthRecur(list, index) {
  var counter = 0
  if (counter === index) {
    return list.value
  } else {
    counter++
    list = list.rest
    return nthRecur(list, index)
  }
}
console.log(nthRecur(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1))
```

Second attempt:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var result = null;
  for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: result
    }
  }
  return result
}
function nthRecur(list, index) {
  var counter = 0
  if (counter === index) {
    return list.value
  } else {
    list = list.rest
    return nthRecur(list, index - 1)
  }
}
console.log(nthRecur(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1))
```

It just worked. I don't know why. Can someone explain?

Comment: Your `counter` variable starts off at 0 every time the function is called.

Comment: So that's why it can't read rest property? That... doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Atheralon That's why it can't read `rest` because when `counter` will always be `0`  in each recursive call then  `counter === index` will never become `true` and code will go to `else` where it will call the function recursively. The `list` will go one step deep each time but `counter` won't change. So at the deepest object the `rest` becomes `null` and it throws error.

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense. Thanks, both of y'all!

Comment: By the way, for your `arrayToList` function, you'll probably want to initialize `var i = array.length - 1;`, otherwise your list represents `[10, 20, undefined]` instead of `[10, 20]`

Comment: Didn't notice that thanks, man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this `counter` is local variable and in each recursive call its set to `0`. You need to create a wrapper function and declare `counter` in it.

```js
var counter = 0;

function arrayToList(array)
{
    var result = null;
    for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result = {
            value: array[i],
            rest: result
        }
    }
    return result
}

function nthRecur(list, index)
{
   let counter = 0;
   function helper(list){
      if(counter === index)
      {
        return list.value
      }
      else
      {
          counter++
          list = list.rest
          return helper(list)
      }
   }
   return helper(list);
   
}
console.log(nthRecur(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten it by using the index directly.

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
    var result = null,
        i = array.length;
    while (i--) {
        result = { value: array[i], rest: result };
    }
    return result;
}


function nthRecur(list, index) {
    return index
        ? nthRecur(list.rest, index - 1)
        : list.value;
}

var list = arrayToList([10, 20, 30]);
console.log(list);
console.log(nthRecur(list, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56891323/1541563), you can add an additional check to each recursion to prevent out of bounds indices from throwing an error:

```js
function arrayToList (array) {
  return array.reduceRight(
    (rest, value) => ({ value, rest }),
    null
  );
}

function item (list, index) {
  return list
    ? index
      ? item(list.rest, index - 1)
      : list.value
    : undefined;
}

const list = arrayToList([10, 20, 30]);

console.log(item(list, 0));
console.log(item(list, 1));
console.log(item(list, 2));
console.log(item(list, 3));
```

If you want to support negative indices as well, similar to [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), you'll need another function to get the `length` of the list and then adjust the `item` function accordingly:

```js
function arrayToList (array) {
  return array.reduceRight(
    (rest, value) => ({ value, rest }),
    null
  );
}

function length (list, index = 0) {
  return list
    ? length(list.rest, index + 1)
    : index;
}

function item (list, index) {
  return list
    ? index
      ? index > 0 || (index += length(list)) > 0
        ? item(list.rest, index - 1)
        : index < 0
          ? undefined
          : list.value
      : list.value
    : undefined;
}

const list = arrayToList([10, 20, 30]);

console.log(item(list, 0));
console.log(item(list, 1));
console.log(item(list, 2));
console.log(item(list, 3));
console.log(item(list, -1));
console.log(item(list, -2));
console.log(item(list, -3));
console.log(item(list, -4));
```

P.S. `arrayToList()` above uses [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to simplify the implementation. `listToArray()` can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and recursion to simplify its implementation:

```js
function arrayToList (array) {
  return array.reduceRight(
    (rest, value) => ({ value, rest }),
    null
  );
}

function listToArray (list, array = []) {
  return list
    ? listToArray(list.rest, [...array, list.value])
    : array;
}

const list = arrayToList([10, 20, 30]);
const array = listToArray(list);

console.log(list);
console.log(array);
```